# jQuery return all items from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JavaScript:

```
function loadDoc(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mytestjson',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        //var txt = result.newBranches[0].newNonBranchLocation;
        $.each(result.newBranches, function(index, txt) 
        {
                // change this to FALSE when ready
                if (newNonBranchLocation.indexOf('TRUE') > -1) {
                        $('#btbumpin').hide();
                    }
            else {
                $('#btbumpin').show();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "errorNode": {
        "errorCode": 0,
        "errorMsg": "",
        "errorSev": ""
    },
    "newBranches": [{
        "cn": "11111101",
        "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
        "newBranchNumber": "111111"
       }, {
        "cn": "11111102",
        "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
        "newBranchNumber": "111111"
       }, {
        "cn": "11111103",
        "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
        "newBranchNumber": "111111"
       }, {
        "cn": "11111181",
        "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
        "newBranchNumber": "111111"
    }]
}
```

I have the above jQuery and JSON. I want to return all the values inside `newBranches` but I am currently only getting the values from the first `newBranches` object

```
    "cn": "11111101",
    "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
    "newBranchNumber": "111111"
```

I want to return `11111101TRUE11111111111102TRUE111111` and so on
i.e. return a string concatenated with all the values in `newBranches`.

Comment: Concatenate all the cn, newNonBranchLocation and newBranchNumber values and return a single string?

Comment: @DVJex yes that is what I want

Comment: @topcat3 then why don't you?

Comment: @zerohero its only returning the first 3 results 11111101TRUE111111 . I would like it to loop through all but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable outside the loop, for ex

```
var output = '';
```

Inside the loop you can just append all the values you need to the variable.

```
output + = txt.cn + txt.newNonBranchLocation + txt.newBranchNumber;
```

After the loop is completed, you can use this variable which will contain the appended string.

Comment: thanks, and if I just wanted to loop through and get all the newNonBranchLocation e.g. TRUETRUETRUETRUE

Comment: @topcat3 Use a variable and use `txt.newNonBranchLocation` alone. Like `output2 + = txt.newNonBranchLocation;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a double `$.Each()` to cross your JSON and add values to a buffer.

```js
$(function() {
        
            var json = {
                "errorNode": {
                "errorCode": 0,
                "errorMsg": "",
                "errorSev": ""
                },
                "newBranches": [{
                    "cn": "11111101",
                    "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
                    "newBranchNumber": "111111"
                }, {
                    "cn": "11111102",
                    "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
                    "newBranchNumber": "111111"
                }, {
                    "cn": "11111103",
                    "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
                    "newBranchNumber": "111111"
                }, {
                    "cn": "11111181",
                    "newNonBranchLocation": "TRUE",
                    "newBranchNumber": "111111"
                }]};
        
                $('body').append(dumpContentOfJSON(json.newBranches));
        
        });
        
        
        
        function dumpContentOfJSON(json) {
            var buffer = '';
            $.each(json, function(index, array) 
            {
                buffer += dumpArray(array);
            });
            return buffer;
        }
        
        function dumpArray(array) {
            var buffer = '';
            $.each(array, function(index,value){
                buffer += value;
            });
            return buffer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```